# Curl обрезает строку

Tags: php, post, curl

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Передаю параметры из скрипта в 1c  при помощи curl. Параметр personalNumber может быть чисто цифрового формата , к примеру 31231233 , и в этом случае все нормально , в 1с данные доходят как надо, а также personalNumber может быть вида 1234ТО-32/100000. И уже в этом случае до 1с доходит урезанный параметр 1234ТО-32. Все что после / включая сам слэш обрезается.  Я так понял это curl каким то образом обрезает строку , но так и не смог понять , как правильно передавать подобного рода данные. В 1с данные приходят уже обрезанные

```
$curl_local = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_local,CURLOPT_URL,"adres/hs/Method/$personalNumber/$thisYear/$dogovor/");
curl_setopt($curl_local,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_local,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_local,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($curl_local,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,0);
curl_setopt($curl_local, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$response_dmz = curl_exec($curl_local);
```

Comment: я так понял , что дело в формате передачи данных adres/hs/Method/$personalNumber/$thisYear/$dogovor/
Если я передаю строку с / то подразумевается , что идет новый параметр , если это так , то наверное надо как то экранировать

Comment: Нужно применять url encoding. К сожалению, на 1с это невозможно 

Answer (score 0):

В итоге выяснил, что символ "/" воспринимается как переход к следующему параметру. Пришлось поколдовать с функциями поиска и замены символов. В php скрипте поменял символ '/' на '^' . В 1с сделал обратную процедуру. И все заработало. Костыль но все же в данном случае он более чем устраивает меня )